# To whom did Reish Lakish sell himself?

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara, translation

In Gittin 46b-47a it discusses the laws when one sells himself to a non-Jew. There it recounts that Reish Lakish sold himself to the Ludai (לודאי). Rashi (end of 46b) and Sefer haAruch explain that this was a race of cannibals. However the translation on [Sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org/Gittin.47a.4?lang=bi) offers the term gladiator instead (this translation is also used by the [Jewish Encyclopedia](http://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/6695-gladiator)). I know that the town of Lud us mentioned frequently in the gemarah but do not know if that is related to לודאי.

I am asking for sources which explain who the לודאי were other than those I have listed here or sources which explain why the term was translated as cannibals or gladiators. If there is a source which explains לודאי as both (cannibal gladiators) I will accept that as well.

Comment: [Jastrow](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/A_Dictionary_of_the_Targumim,_the_Talmud_Babli_and_Yerushalmi,_and_the_Midrashic_Literature/%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%93%D7%90%D7%94_-_%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%96) translates לודאה as "people hiring men for gladiatorial contests".

Comment: _Ludus_ (similar to the Hebrew word _luda'ah_) means several things related to gladiators in Latin. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ludus_(ancient_Rome)).

Comment: Sorry to comment once again, but I have heard many people say that Reish Lakish joined a circus, so maybe they've found a connection between circus and _ludai_?

Comment: [Graetz](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heinrich_Graetz) has dealt with the inaccurate transl. of cannibal in his History of The Jews ([here](https://books.google.com/books?id=b3Y-AQAAMAAJ&lpg=PA335&ots=Pkk7iGfiv4&dq=%D7%92%D7%99%D7%98%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%93%D7%90%D7%99%20%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%A9%20%D7%9C%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%A9&pg=PA335#v=onepage&q&f=false), in the Hebrew ed.) and cites [Sachs](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Sachs) as having demonstrated its correct interpretation: a (circus) member who performed as gladiator.

Comment: http://cal.huc.edu/oneentry.php?lemma=lwdy%20N&cits=all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After having researched the matter it appears that gladiator is the preferred translation by scholars. In an extensive footnote (6) professor [Marc Brettler](https://www.academia.edu/8286122/Rabbi_Simeon_ben_Lakish_at_the_Gladiator_s_Banquet_Rabbinic_Observations_on_the_Roman_Arena) traces the roots of this translation. He opines that Rashi's translation of cannibals is based on a faulty text, but does not explain if Aruch had the same text or not. He mentions professor Jastrow as the first to 'correctly' translate the term. He also offers a possible explanation for the translation of 'circus' mentioned in a [comment](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/87792/to-whom-did-reish-lakish-sell-himself?noredirect=1#comment281858_87792) as deriving from the Greek for games/stage performers.

The reading of gladiator seems to be confirmed from the implication of the rest of the paper, in that the ritual that Reish Lakish participated in (*cena*) was in line with what took place during gladiator banquets/events.

There does not seem to be a connection to the town of Lud but rather Lydia.

Comment: There's no connection to Lydia either, to my knowledge. The word is connected to the Latin word _ludus_, meaning "game" or "sport" and in Roman culture referred to gladiatorial games as well. See my second comment above.