Is there any reason to suppose that "Reish Lakish" means something like "chief of the bandits"?
I feel like I've heard this many times over the years. In the last couple of days I've shopped the question around, and everyone seems to have heard the theory that because of his colorful past, Reish Lakish was so-called because it means "chief of the bandits."
It doesn't seem to make much sense. Jastrow doesn't list such a word, Lakish = bandit. It seems hard to reconcile with the frequently-used Shimon Ben Lakish, unless that Ben is taken to mean something like the Ben of Ben Torah. And it would seem rather strange to call him forever by reference to his former bad character which he so greatly improved. To me it seems much more natural to assume that Reish is a contraction of Rav Shimon, used just because there were a lot of Shimons to be distinguished.
Anyhow, is there any source or good reason to the view that Reish Lakish means something like "chief of the bandits"?

One rebbe of mine thought he was a French chef -- Riche Le-Quiche. But I'd never heard anything other than it was a contraction of his name... or maybe, maybe "Reish" was a reference to him being a chief of something. But not that "Lakish" meant bandit.

Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/111086/why-wasnt-reish-lakish-punished-for-his-crimes-as-a-bandit, https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/87792/to-whom-did-reish-lakish-sell-himself.

R’ Yochanan (Bava Metzia 84a) refers to Reish Lakish as “Bar Lekisha”. The added alef seems to indicate that “Lakish” is more than just a name.
Lekisha translates as “the late one”. (See Targum Onkelos, Bereishis 30:42; Vayikra Rabbah 30:3.) This is one of the reasons the late rain is called מלקוש. Perhaps the name “Reish Lakish” alludes to his belated devotion to Torah study, dubbing him “the Latecomer” — and indeed, “the Head of the Latecomers”.

Your suggestion is a good idea, shkoyech. Alternatively, R' Prof. Shmuel Klein suggested that he was born a "latecomer", i.e., born late in the life of his father/parents. https://www.jstor.org/stable/24384313. Compare the tanna Rabbi Yehudah ben Lakish. https://www.sefaria.org.il/search?q=%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95%D7%93%D7%94%20%D7%91%D7%9F%20%D7%9C%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%A9&tab=text&tvar=0&tsort=relevance&svar=1&ssort=relevance.

Re your first paragraph: it's not just the extra aleph. The context there is R. Yochanan bewailing the loss of Reish Lakish - which had been triggered by a discussion in which R. Yochanan called attention to Reish Lakish's past, to which Reish Lakish took offense! Certainly, then, under those conditions, R. Yochanan would hardly continue to call his departed colleague by a name that would once again call attention to it.

Good point. Although one might suggest that it has the opposite connotation; originally R’ Yochanan had referred to the sins of his youth, whereas here he points out his later atonement. He now recognizes that no one can compare to Reish Lakish despite his delayed start.

It seems that the nickname Reish Lakish of R. Shimon ben Lakish is a play on words. Lakish was the name of R. Shimon's father, and it means "the late one" as explained Yø-c Ro. However, for R. Shimon the nickname was used as a hint ריש מלקה איש - Reish Malkeh Ish - Chief hitter of men (Thank you Harel13!), as in Mishna Makkos 3:3 " לוֹקֶה אַרְבָּעִים " - flogged with forty lashes.
We can infer the etymology as follows. In the final conflict with R. Yochanan in Bava Metzia 84a R. Shimon b. Lakish says to R. Yochanah:

אֲמַר לֵיהּ: וּמַאי אַהֲנֵית לִי? הָתָם ״רַבִּי״ קָרוּ לִי, הָכָא ״רַבִּי״ קָרוּ לִי!
Reish Lakish said to Rabbi Yoḥanan: What benefit did you provide me by bringing me close to Torah? There, (among the bandits), they called me: Rabbi (literally Leader/Great Man), and here (among Torah scholars), too, they call me: Rabbi.

The description of what R. Shimon did before he became a rabbi is given in Gittin 47a also here

The Gemara recounts a related incident: Reish Lakish sold himself to gladiators. He took a bag and a round stone inside of it with him. He said: There is a tradition that on the final day of a captive’s life, before his captors kill him, they do for him anything that he requests of them, so that he would forgive them for the spilling of his blood. On the final day before they were set to kill him they said to him: What is amenable to you? He said to them: I want to tie you up and have you sit, and I will אֶמְחְיֵהּ/strike each one of you one and a half times. He tied them up and had each one of them sit. When he struck each of them with one strike with the stone in the bag, the one whom he struck died, because Reish Lakish was of great strength. Reish Lakish gritted his teeth in anger, and said to the one whom he killed, in order to prevent the others from realizing what was happening: Are you laughing at me? You still have half of a strike remaining with me, as I struck you only once. He killed them all, and Reish Lakish escaped his captors.

The Aramaic word מחי is the same as Hebrew מכה and מלקה is used in the context of מכות.

Interesting! Do you have a source for this?

@Yø-cRo I do not, I added to the answer how I made the inference.

In the quotation from Bava Metzia, Reish Lakish seems to say only "They called me Rabbi there, and they call me Rabbi here." Why do you translate it as you do, "leader of bandits," and with "among the bandits" also seeming to have no corresponding words in the original?

@Chaim I used Sefaria translation. The literal meaning of the word Rabbi is My Great Man i.e. leader.
